# FileReader advantages vs. FileInputStream advantages

Tags: java, io

From what I can read on Stack Overflow, the *FileReader* only takes files, where the *FileInputStream* can read all. But is there any advantages in using the *FileReader* then? Is it faster?

I read that:

> "FileReader does not allow you to specify an encoding and instead uses
>   the plaform default encoding, which makes it pretty much useless as
>   using it will result in corrupted data when the code is run on systems
>   with different platform default encodings."

But didn't quite get it. What does platform default encodings mean?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155226/fileinputstream-vs-filereader?rq=1

Answer (score 14):

The Main difference is:
**Stream** - Byte Based(Read or write Bytes)
**Reader** - Character Based(Read or Write Character)

Comment: What do you mean by byte Based? is it read just one byte at a time?

Answer (score 13):

- An `InputStream` is a stream from which you can read bytes.  You wouldn't normally use this class directly, but if you did, you'd be expecting binary data.  It has many different subclasses for input from different sources, such as `FileInputStream`, `AudioInputStream`, `StringBufferInputStream` and so on.
- An `InputStreamReader` is a wrapper for an `InputStream`, that converts the stream's bytes into characters, using any encoding you like.  Normally, you specify the character encoding when you create the `InputStreamReader`.  There are a few different constructors that let you do this.  If you want to read text data, you could use an `InputStreamReader`.  Make your `InputStream` first to read the data, then wrap it in an `InputStreamReader`.
- A `FileReader` is a specialised `InputStreamReader` that can only read from files, and uses the default platform encoding.  In other words, it assumes that the file that it reads has been created according to your operating system's settings for platform encoding.  This is usually OK; but if you're going to be reading files with different encodings, you should create a `FileInputStream` and wrap it in an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: But lets say I have a txt file. Is there any advantages in using the FileReader?

Comment: @user3161344 Yes, that is what a FileReader is for.  FileInputStream is for reading binary.

Comment: Yes.  It saves you the hassle of converting bytes to characters yourself, which is not a trivial problem.

Comment: But in a program I made I used the FileInputStream to do that. So im trying to find out what the advantages might be.

Comment: No.  A `FileInputStream` doesn't convert bytes to characters.  If you want to get a `String` out of a `FileInputStream`, you need to convert them using some other mechanism.

Comment: FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filnavn); DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

Was how I did it

Comment: I see an `InputStreamReader` lurking in that snippet.

Comment: Ah yeah. But I might aswell have used a Filereader. Is it any quicker with a FileReader since it only handles chars?

Comment: A `FileReader` is an `InputStreamReader`.  It's a subclass.  So it's using the same code - it's not going to outperform `InputStreamReader`.  What it doesn't do is buffering - you've put in your own `BufferedReader`, so you've already dealt with that, and that may help you with performance.  Also, get rid of the `DataInputStream` - you're not actually using its functionality at all.

Answer (score 2):

Platform default encoding, means the encoding used by the OS, that the JVM is running on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Windows go to Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options Control Panel -> Advanced there you will see default encoding. FileReader always uses that encoding.

What makes FileReader different from FileInputStream is that FileReader is for reading text files in default encoding while FileInputStream is for reading binary files.

Answer (score 0):

A `FileReader` is a character stream while a `FileInputStream` is a byte stream. In the first case default encoding is relevant (consider for example `InputStreamReader` as intermedium bridge).

If you want another encoding for a character stream (that is a `Reader`) then use:

```
FileInputStream in = ...;
String charSet = ...; // for example UTF-8
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, charSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` are used for object serialization / deserialization.
Also just use it if you need to work with bytes.

In other cases, you need characters, so you should use `FileReader`/`FileWriter`.
For example:

```
BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```