# What is difference between FileReader and FileInputStream in Java?

Tags: java

I know both FileReader and FileInputStream are used to read data from a file in Java. but don't know difference between them and which one appropriate in which case? I surfed internet but not found satisfied answer?

Comment: Also Have a look into http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/04/difference-between-fileinputstream-and-filereader-in-java.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: [FileReader vs FileInputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155226/fileinputstream-vs-filereader) The correct answer tells the main difference between these streams. Also recommend to read about char and byte streams.

Comment: Did you consider consulting the documentation that is provided for the purpose?

Comment: this link will help you   http://java67.blogspot.in/2016/03/difference-between-filereader-vs.html#more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From oracle docs:

> A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. What files are available depends on the host environment.
>   **FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.**