# Reading huge textfiles Java

Tags: java, stream, text-files

I've got a .txt with 1 Billion digits of pi. I read in the file as a String but i get an OutOfMemoryError. It worked with 1 MIllion digits tho. I save the String as a char[] array.
Is it possible to somehow stream the .txt when i cycle through the whole array? I simply need a way to have access to all the 1 Billion digits as an array.

Comment: What kind of processing do you need to do with the read data ?

Comment: I am cycling through the entire char array to look for a certain number...so just a for loop through the array. Thats it

Comment: What do you mean by "look for a certain number"? The number is pi. Do you mean "look for a specific sequence of digits"? If so, how many digits?

Comment: yes, a sequence of digits. well about 4-9 or something like that. I need a way to have access to all the 1 billion digits as an array

Comment: Why do you “need a way to have access to all the 1 billion digits as an array”? If you have a string, you can iterate over the `char`s, just as you can with an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is BufferedInputStream since java 1 or FileReader with

```
public int read(char cbuf[], int offset, int length) throws IOException
```

I suggest you start from there

Comment: This is probably the solution for my problem. got problems implementing tho.. ._.  Ill keep trying

Comment: Where’s the relevance of `BufferedInputStream` here?

Comment: You right,  I should have mentioned FileInputStream, which has buffer on it's own, so theres no there's no need for BufferedInputStream. This might be usefull here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155226/fileinputstream-vs-filereader

Answer (score 0):

It is not only possible: it is both **highly recommended and done in practice**. What is usually done is to reuse the same kind of interfaces as Java libraries (InputStream, etc).

In this case, this could mean a new IntegerInputStream class that outputs the digits as a stream. This class can itself forward calls to `FileInputStream`. Internally, you can use char[] arrays to store the buffer and improve performance, or have calls directed via `BufferedInputStream` as Pavel suggests, but it is best to isolate the consumer from the internal buffer management and keep the appropriate level of abstraction to the use case (decimals of pi).

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file with a `FileInputStream`, and read it byte[] per byte[] to avoid the OOMError.

Answer (score 0):

According to doc

> You should be able to get a String of length Integer.MAX_VALUE (always 2147483647 (231 - 1) by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage) or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller

This is why you get  the Exception,

if you don't really need the whole 1B chars. you can try using buffer which doesn't load the whole thing into memory.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("path to file")));
char[] data=new char[1000000] ;//however many chars you want;
int i=0;
while ((c = br.read()) != -1 && i<data.length) {
    data[i++]= c;
}

br.close();
```

Comment: Why on earth are you reading up to 1000000 single characters instead of calling just `read(char[])` on the reader? Then, you don’t need a `BufferedReader` to work around the excessive `read()` invocations…

Comment: @Holger I guess that's another way of doing it. In terms of complexity both solution should be about the same. but yeah I agree that one liner solution is better